# Is palmistry a part of astrology?

Tags: astrology

How can one judge our Graha-dosha by reading only hasth-rekha? 
I think from kundli it can be done but how from hastha-rekha? Probably our groha changes in every ten years but does also hasth-rekha changes?

Comment: Why it can't be done? Even from our face or other parts of our body an adept astrologer can predict a lot of things. Its part of samudra sastra.

Comment: Also in our natal chart the grahas are fixed, however in the transit chart they change...and if u are a good observer then u can even notice subtle changes in ur palm lines which evolved with time..

Comment: I guess it changes during our grown up times but not that much after our middle age

Comment: No they can change even after ur body stops growing..You have to be a keen observer.

Comment: Also u need the change the title to something else. Scientific speculation is off-topic here.

Comment: I read a book on palmistry by Chiero but that does not inspire me. Can you suggest me some Bengali book or astrology?

Comment: Ok i will definitely do that Let me collect some book names.

Comment: Another question: Can you suggest me some apps or online sites where I can make kusthi/kundli using only date and time of birth. Thanks.

Comment: Yes there are many such sites. This one is good: http://astrobix.com/horoscope/birthchart/

Comment: Sorry i completely forgot that i am supposed to give u the book names. Do u want them in Eng or Beng? anyways, here are few books in Bengali . They are of preliminary nature but by studying them u can learn the subject. 
Samudrik Vigyan, Samudrik Rekha Vichar (Raman Krishna Chattopadhya), Hath Dekha Sikkha (Paresh Das Burman). [Publisher-Tara library] ... Sachitra Hasta Rekha Vichar o Vigyan. (Sri Surendra Nath Bhattacharya Jyotis Shastri author)

Comment: You are welcome. BTW u can easily get them in College Street book shops.

Answer (score 2):

If you take your palm print every year. You can easily see after 10-15 years that it changes! There is no doubt about it.

Palmistry is part of astrology. In ancient India, Palmistry was known as "Samudrika Shastra".

World's most famous palmist Cheiro learned palmistry from an Indian Brahmin from Maharastra. He mentioned that in his biography.

Ref: Language of the hand by Cheiro
https://www.amazon.in/Cheiros-Language-Hand-Cheiro-ebook/dp/B07C38PKKM/ref=tmm_kin_swatch_0?_encoding=UTF8&qid=1559207417&sr=8-3

By the way, most of the horoscope analysis is done based on the position of planets at the time of native's birth. Your horoscope is basically the snapshot of the sky when you were born. That is why they ask for three info: date of birth, time of birth and place of birth. This snapshot varies depending on time and place. So it is the analysis of **fixed** planetary positions during your birth that predicts your entire life! Only the transit (or gochara) analysis takes into account of changing planetary positions with time.

Comment: You should cite some sources.

Comment: @Pandya What sources are needed? Can you elaborate Pandya? The OP edited after citation notice. Is that enough? Let the rest of the users also know what is missing in the answer so that they will know when to flag for removal or edit properly.